# S1000D Conditional Documentation Workflow

Tags: xml, database-design, xsd, database-schema

Fellow Forum Members,

My ojective is to setup a S1000D Conditional Documenation workflow using the suite of PTC apps shown below:

CSDB for S1000D (Control Station)
CSDB for S1000D (Task Station)
Publisher for S1000D
Provisioning Manager
Parts Catalog Manager
LSA Interface

The plan is to populate the CSDB (Common Source Data Base) with modules that are going to be used as building blocks for technical manuals. Once this is done, my goal is to be able ot build Technical Manuals using the Alias and/or Container feature that is part of the S1000D standard.

I want to be able to perform conditional documentation operations where changing the source module located in the CSDB dynamically updates all of the modules linked to it. My question is as follows. Is this conditional documentation capability I'm aiming for best done using the Container feature or the Alias feature?

I would appreciate hearing from someone out there who has S1000D knowledge as it relates to how best perform conditional documenation that is dynamically linked to a single source module.  Thanks in advance and any info will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is _WAY_ off-topic for SO, which is about programming/coding questions.

Answer (score 1):

@Jim Garrison Actually, this is a type of programming, although it's exceedingly specialized.

Before you go any further, you'll have to:

1. Identify which Issue of the S1000D Specification you are using.
2. Find your project's BREX module (Specification Tailoring) to determine which features of the specification your project is using.  There's no point working out a complex solution with containers if your project disallows them.
3. Look at the documentation for your CSDB to see if it handles containers.  Not all of them do.

If you are looking for information re-use, where you have common language that appears in multiple places, then you may want to look into the Technical Information Repository (for Issue 3.0 and 4.0) or the Common Information Repository (for Issue 4.1).  If you use that facility combined with applicability statements, you may get the behavior I think you are after.